# Short-circuit logic evaluation in 'if' statement

Tags: r

I'm looking to add a short-circuit to an if statement. The idea is that if both refEndDate and the last item in endDateList are NA, don't perform the second operation but still return true. Currently, both sides of the `&&` gets run which can result in an error if refEndDate or the last entry in endDateList are NA.

```
endDateList <- c('2018-01-01', '2018-01-03', NA)
refEndDate <- NA


(is.na(endDateList[length(endDateList)]) & is.na(refEndDate))
[1] TRUE
```

This returns TRUE as expected.

```
(endDateList[length(endDateList)] != refEndDate)
[1] NA
```

This returns NA as expected as both are NA.

```
((is.na(endDateList[length(endDateList)]) & is.na(refEndDate)) &&
    (endDateList[length(endDateList)] != refEndDate))
[1] NA
```

How do I get the above to return TRUE?

Comment: What does the 2nd statement do? If 1 is true, regardless of the value of 2, then the result should be `TRUE`. If 1 is false, then the result should be false (because you put an `&` there). Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use an or instead of an and.

```
((is.na(endDateList[length(endDateList)]) & is.na(refEndDate)) || 
       (endDateList[length(endDateList)] != refEndDate))
[1] TRUE
```

You should understand what an logical `NA` means.  `NA` means that the value isn't known, **but it still needs to be `TRUE` or `FALSE`**.  In other words, if a statement always evaluates one way regardless of the status of the `NA` value, it will not return `NA`.

For example, consider the following cases:

```
> TRUE || NA
[1] TRUE

> FALSE || NA
[1] NA

> TRUE && NA
[1] NA

> FALSE && NA
[1] FALSE
```